# Powershell, calling API with Invoke-RestMethod results in double execution

Tags: powershell, rest

I have an API, which I'm calling in Powershell using the [Invoke-Restmethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2) like this

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri http://localhost:3030/api/startSync -TimeoutSec 2147483647
```

This results in the API method being called twice. One time immediately, and another time exactly 120 seconds after the first call. If I call the API method using another client, it gets called only once (so it seems not to be a problem within the API method itself, but in the Invoke-RestMethod call). I could not find any documentation about this. What is the reason for this and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Personally I have never seen this behaviour when using `Invoke-restmethod` when working with any API (Inclusive of custom locally created API endpoints). Could you confirm that you are only calling this cmdlet the once? Also why have you set the the `-TimeoutSec` to what would be 68 years?

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you replace `Invoke-RestMethod` with `Invoke-WebRequest`? Is that the only code you are calling, or is there more code before and around the API call?

Comment: @CraftyB I'm positive I called the cmdlet only once (the strange behaviour was repeatedly reproducible). The TimeoutSec was set to the max Int32 value simply to prevent a timeout (but reading the documentation shows that it is unnecessary, as per default there is no timeout)

Comment: @Ash Thank you! Using Invoke-WebRequest seemed to prevent the "double" request.

Comment: I used  Invoke-WebRequest without -TimeoutSec argument, which seemed to solve the problem. So it's not about the command, but about the -TimeoutSec which introduces undocumented behaviour. I'll post an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is some undocumented behaviour when using the PowerShell commands `Invoke-Restmethod` and `Invoke-WebRequest`: when the `TimeoutSec` option is used, the command is repeated 120 seconds after the first call, if there is no response until that. If the `TimeoutSec` option is not used, this does not happen (but there is an error message after ca. 115 seconds).

Tested with PowerShell 5.

**Solution**: run the command without `TimeoutSec` or modify the API call so that a result is returned before 120 seconds, even though the job continues running in the background.